# Spring data jdbc and querydsl calls in one transaction do not work

Tags: spring, querydsl, spring-data-jdbc, infobip

I'm using spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc and infobip-spring-data-jdbc-querydsl-boot-starter(5.4.2) together.
In my tests with org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional annotation I have the following code:

```
@Transactional
void test() {
    repository.save(ReportList.builder().userName("username").build());

    var reports = repository.query(query -> query
            .select(entityProjection())
            .from(QReportList.reportList)
            .fetch());
}
```

**Expected result:** variable reports is not empty
**Actual result:** variable reports is empty

If I remove @Transactional (or use default findAll method from QuerydslJdbcRepository) it starts to return results.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

After some time of digging I found the following lines of code:

```
public class SQLQueryFactory extends AbstractSQLQueryFactory<SQLQuery<?>> {

    static class DataSourceProvider implements Provider<Connection> {

        @Override
        public Connection get() {
            try {
                return ds.getConnection();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
```

`ds.getConnection()` returns new connection instead of existing one (with transaction).

I added `querydsl-sql-spring` with the following configuration and my code start to work as expected:

```
@Bean
public SQLQueryFactory queryFactory(com.querydsl.sql.Configuration configuration, DataSource dataSource) {
   var provider = new SpringConnectionProvider(dataSource);
   return new SQLQueryFactory(configuration, provider);
}
```